# UserDetailsService Not Getting Called

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have this Spring XML:

```
    <!-- Configure the authentication  -->
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
                             authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
                             default-target-url="/index" />

        <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
                         logout-success-url="/login"
                         logout-url="/logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="testUDS" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="testUDS" class="net.safecycle.services.security.TestUserDetailService" />
```

My UserDetailsService implementation looks like this:

```
public class TestUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername 
    (
        String username
    ) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println ("loadUserByUsername (" + username + ")");

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
        authorities = new LinkedList<GrantedAuthority> ();
        authorities.add (new GrantedAuthorityImpl ("Admin"));

        UserDetails ud = new User (username, 
                                   "ca", 
                                   true, 
                                   true, 
                                   true, 
                                   true, 
                                   authorities);
        return ud;
    }
}
```

When I log in with any username and the password 'ca', I should see the print statement at the top of my `loadUserByUsername`, but I do not. What is most perplexing is that I have used this code in another project with no problem. Is there anything I am missing, a copy mistake I'm hoping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify which resources are protected

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
```

Comment: That gets me into a redirect loop. I have also tried `pattern="/**" access="permitAll"` and that gave me the same result as my original question.

Comment: @Nik Enable logging to figure out the problem, add log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG if you have log4j.properties

Comment: The problem ended up being with the HTML form in my log in code. It was figured out thanks to your logging suggestion. Thank you much.

Comment: @Nik what HTML form issue you found can you please let me know, b'coz I also have same issue?

Comment: This is from 4 years ago, I have no recollection, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code from my xml file. Only missing thing is the allias.. try to add alias="authenticationManager" maybe it will help.

```
<beans:bean id="CustomUserDetailsService"
    class="com.dennis.ehospital.hibernate.security.CustomUserDetailsService" />

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="CustomUserDetailsService" />
</authentication-manager>
```