# In Spring Security 3.1 i am using form based authentication and want to put additional attributes in UserDetails object 

Tags: spring-security, spring-3

I am new to Springs and not a advanced programmer of java.

I am creating a prototype where i am using Springs security. 
to keep it simple i am using JSP form based user authentication and have some dummy users in my applicationContext-security.xml

```
<security:http auto-config='true'>
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
  <security:authentication-provider>
    <security:user-service>
      <security:user name="foo" password="foo" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
      <security:user name="bob" password="bob" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </security:user-service>
  </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

The idea is that later this authentication method will be replaced by OpenId authentication.

Now what i need is once the user is authenticated, using the authenticated username i would like to retrieve additional details of the user from a database table and put it in Springs UserDetails object so that its available to me all the time

what i have researched so far is that i need to create my Custom UserDetailsService

my question is if i am using springs standard authentication method do i need to create a custom UserDetailsService ?
I just want to store some additional details reading it from a database.

i have gone through many examples but none of them answers this particular issue.
also since i am little new to these technologies. i get lost no how to tie the code snippets together. any help to point me to right direction would be great

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Generally you need a custom `UserDetailsService` which returns your extended `UserDetails` object with the additional properties you want. You'll find plenty of example configurations if you search SO, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9074761/241990), for example.

Strictly speaking, you don't have to use a `UserDetailsService` or implement `UserDetails` (you can implement `AuthenticationProvider` directly), but it's the easiest approach to being with and probably where you should start.

Comment: awesome, that is what i was looking for. very simple and straight forward example for beginners like me.

can you tell me one more thing once i change my authentication process to OpenID then this custom implementation will be gone. but i would still like to store some extra attributes in userDetails. That is i like to get authenticated from an OpenID service such as Gmail. if the authentication is successful then based on the email i would do a local serach in my database and load some extra attributes in userdetails obj. Is that possible ? or do you have any other suggestion to achieve this

Comment: It's very similar. Look at the OpenID sample code in the Spring Security codebase. It uses a custom `UserDetails` object with attributes pulled from the OpenID provider. Adding some local JDBC code should be trivial.